# offset for weekend days using mod

Tags: vb.net, offset, weekend

I have a .NET console app that needs to run on the 1st, 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th, and 25th of each month. Depending on which date it runs, the app sends out a different type of email. I want to adjust the app so that if one of those dates is on the weekend, it runs the following Monday.

I believe this does what I want:

```
Dim adjustedDay As Integer = Day(Today)
If Today.ToString("ddd") = "Mon" And adjustedDay > 1 Then
    If adjustedDay Mod 5 = 1 Then
        adjustedDay -= 1
    ElseIf adjustedDay Mod 5 = 2 Then
        adjustedDay -= 2
    End If
End If
Select Case adjustedDay
    Case 1
          ...
    Case 5
          ...
    Case ...
          ...
End Select
```

So if today is Monday, 9/21/2015, I adjust to "20" and run that code. If Monday happens to land on the 1st, I don't adjust it.

is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: So if it is saturday you want to add 2 and if sunday you want to add 1? (DateTime.AddDays should be enough)

Comment: You should read up on the properties of the [DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the DayOfWeek property in particular.

Comment: @Steve, yes, but there are specific conditions to the logic that prevent me from simply adding days. What I'm trying to do is check the date on Monday, and if Monday is one or two days after the 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th or 25th, run the code that would run on that day. Unless Monday is the 1st of the month, in which case don't adjust.

Comment: @TnTinMn, DayOfWeek just gets me to the second line of code. My issue is I have different conditions that are affected by the day of the month, not just the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work correctly if Monday falls on the 2nd or 3rd of the month. (ie. 2 mod 5 = 2, so adjustedDay = 0)

The other tricky part is that the app needs to run on the 1st, but 1 mod 5 = 1 which is different to all the other cases where it is 0.

Something like this should work:

```
'Returns 0 for non-email days, otherwise returns 1,5,10,15,20,25
Private Function GetEmailDay(ByVal currentDate as Date) As Integer
    If currentDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse
        currentDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        Return 0
    End If

    Dim day As Integer = currentDate.Day

    Dim emailDays As New List(Of Integer)( {1,5,10,15,20,25} )
    If emailDays.Contains(day) Then
        Return day
    End If

    If currentDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        If emailDays.Contains(day-1) Then 'check Sunday
            Return day-1
        End If
        If emailDays.Contains(day-2) Then 'check Saturday
            Return day-2
        End If
    End If

    Return 0
End Function
```